# How do I replace special characters with regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace special characters from a string, like this:

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/\n/g,'');
```

Except for the regex part, I need it to look for the **opposite** of all these:

> [0-9]  Find any digit from 0 to 9
>   [A-Z]  Find any character from uppercase A to uppercase Z
>   [a-z]  Find any character from lowercase a to lowercase z

plus `underscore` and `minus`.

Therefore, this string is OK:

> Abc054_34-bd

And this string is bad:

> Fš 04//4.

From the bad string I need the disallowed characters removed.

How do I stack this regex rule?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use character class with `^` negation:

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/g,'');
```

**Tests:**

```
console.log('Abc054_34-bd'.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/g,'')); // Abc054_34-bd
console.log('Fš 04//4.'.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/g,'')); // F044
```

So by putting characters in `[^...]`, you can decide which characters should be allowed and all others replaced.