# Regular expression - replace special characters, except dot

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

```
$('#price').keyup(function(){
        $('#price').val($('#price').val().replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-"));
})
```

See it live at: http://jsfiddle.net/2KRHh/6/.

This removes special characters, but how can I specify that it not replace dots?

Comment: This probably isn't a good way to accomplish what you want. Say I copy and paste some special characters into it, using the mouse, it won't trigger the keyup function.

Comment: You can change the regex to list the characters you want to _keep_ instead of the ones you want to replace. Combine with the ^ operator.

Comment: Almost duplicate: [stackoverflow.com/questions/9311258/how-do-i-replace-special-characters-with-regex-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311258/how-do-i-replace-special-characters-with-regex-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7):

Use this for the regex instead:

```
 /[^\w.]|_/g
```

It reads any character that is *not* either alpha-numerical (which includes underbars) or dot, *or* that *is* an under bar.

**update**
But this is perhaps little more readable:

```
/[^0-9a-zA-Z.]/g
```

Comment: I think you meant to add a "\" in the regular expression: `/([^\w.])|_/g` Also, why have you added a capture group around the `[^\w.]` character class?

Comment: but this replace also digits. This should allow digit 0-9 and numbers

Comment: @sigpwned: the capture group is not necessary.

Comment: @Horn: the \w means any char that is a number or a letter or _, while the ^ at the beginning of the character class means anything that is *not* one of these, so this will not replace digits.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit old now but in case someone still need it, Faust's answer didn't work for me (I tried to change a file's name to use it in a URL) so here's the solution I found :

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9.\-]/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Reread the question, they want to replace special characters **except dot**, so hyphen has to be removed.